# Bash: run service if not already running (Centos, Apache, Clam)

Tags: bash, apache, centos

Wrote a simple bash script which is to be run in order to check if httpd (apache) or clamd (antivirus) is running on my Centos server, and if not it will restart them.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! "$(/sbin/service httpd status)" =~ "running" ]]
then
    service httpd start
elif [[ ! "$(/sbin/service clamd status)" =~ "running" ]]
then 
    service clamd start
fi
```

tested it via the command line so it works, but is there any way to optimize this further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop caring about the text and just check the return values.

```
#!/bin/sh
service httpd status &> /dev/null || service httpd start
service clamd status &> /dev/null || service clamd start
```

Or just don't care that they're already running and let the system handle it.

```
#!/bin/sh
service httpd start
service clamd start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# First parameter is a comma-delimited string i.e. service1,service2,service3
SERVICES=$1

if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
  if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "root privileges are required" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
  exit 1
fi

for service in ${SERVICES//,/ }
do
    STATUS=$(service ${service} status | awk '{print $2}')

    if [ "${STATUS}" != "started" ]; then
        echo "${service} not started"

        #DO STUFF TO SERVICE HERE
    fi
done
```